# Python 3.4 Django 1.8 PythonAnywhere ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8, pythonanywhere

Trying to deploy my project on pythonanywhere.

- python3.4
- Django 1.8.7
- Username - GriMel
- Project name - TwDTutor

**wsgi configuration file**

```
import os
import sys
path = '/home/GriMel/TwDTutor'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'TwDTutor.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Static files**

```
/static/admin   /home/GriMel/.virtualenvs/rango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
/static/    /home/GriMel/TwDTutor/rango/static
```

Get the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error usually indicates that there's a Django version mismatch so you probably haven't set the virtualenv correctly on the web app tab.